# AUTO INSERTING IDENTITY KEY TO STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am writing code to insert data into an existing table using AdventureWorks2012 in T-SQL. I want the code to generate the ID for the newly inserted rows automatically. I have the code writing as below. The message indicated that the code successfully completed. However, when called the procedure, I got the error message as

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure insertprocEPH, Line 13
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BusinessEntityID', table 'AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.The statement has been terminated.

Here is my code. Please let me know what is wrong with the code. Thank you all

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'HumanResources.insertprocEPH', N'P') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE HumanResources.insertprocEPH
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.insertprocEPH
(
    @RateChangeDate     DATETIME        ,
    @Rate               MONEY           ,
    @PayFrequency       TINYINT = 2     ,
    @BusinessEntityID   INT     OUTPUT      
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory(RateChangeDate, Rate, PayFrequency)
        VALUES(@RateChangeDate, @Rate, @PayFrequency);

        SET @BusinessEntityID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
   END;
   GO

   DECLARE @NewBEntityID INT;

   EXEC HumanResources.insertprocEPH
        @RateChangeDate = '2012-05-25',
        @Rate = 4,
        @BusinessEntityID = @NewBEntityID OUTPUT
   GO
```

Comment: It looks like `BusinessEntityID` is not defined as an auto-increment column.

Answer (score 0):

`HumanResource.EmployePayHistory.BusinessEntityID` column doesn't have `IDENTITY` property:

```
Column_name      Type      Computed Length      Prec  Scale Nullable                           
---------------- --------- -------- ----------- ----- ----- --------
BusinessEntityID int       no       4           10    0     no                                 
RateChangeDate   datetime  no       8                       no                                 
Rate             money     no       8           19    4     no                                 
PayFrequency     tinyint   no       1           3     0     no                                 
ModifiedDate     datetime  no       8                       no                                 


Identity                    Seed Increment Not For Replication
--------------------------- ---- --------- -------------------
No identity column defined. NULL NULL      NULL
```

[image]

Also, `HumanResource.EmployeePayHistory.BusinessEntityID` is a foreign key pointing to `HumanResources.Employee.BusinessEntityID` primary key.

This means that you should insert into `HumanResource.EmployeePayHistory.BusinessEntityID` (FK) a value which already exists in `HumanResources.Employee.BusinessEntityID` (PK).

See [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).